# How to check if the given string is palindrome?

Tags: string, language-agnostic

**Definition:**

*A palindrome is a word, phrase, number or other sequence of units that has the property of reading the same in either direction*

How to check if the given string is a palindrome?

This was one of the FAIQ [Frequently Asked Interview Question] a while ago but that mostly using C.

Looking for solutions in any and all languages possible.

Comment: A man, a plan, a canal, Panama

Comment: Go hang a salami. I'm a lasagna hog.

Comment: Do you care about punctuation? Case? What about locale-sensitive case folding?

Comment: well, i didnt think of punctuation issues which could be ignored!

Comment: I'm disappointed that, as far as I can tell, no one implemented it with a stack.

Comment: @NickHodges, I agree. Push on each character and pop off and compare as you iterate down the string.

Answer (score 46):

**PHP sample**:

```
$string = "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama";

function is_palindrome($string)
{
    $a = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$string));
    return $a==strrev($a);
}
```

Removes any non-alphanumeric characters (spaces, commas, exclamation points, etc.) to allow for full sentences as above, as well as simple words.

Comment: It doesn't work for numbers and languages other then English.

Comment: Just curious - why not strtolower() first so you have a shorter regex?

Answer (score 34):

Windows XP (might also work on 2000) or later BATCH script:

```
@echo off

call :is_palindrome %1
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo %1 is a palindrome
) else (
    echo %1 is NOT a palindrome
)
exit /B 0

:is_palindrome
    set word=%~1
    set reverse=
    call :reverse_chars "%word%"
    set return=1
    if "$%word%" == "$%reverse%" (
        set return=0
    )
exit /B %return%

:reverse_chars
    set chars=%~1
    set reverse=%chars:~0,1%%reverse%
    set chars=%chars:~1%
    if "$%chars%" == "$" (
        exit /B 0
    ) else (
        call :reverse_chars "%chars%"
    )
exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 30):

Language agnostic meta-code then...

```
rev = StringReverse(originalString)
return ( rev == originalString );
```

Comment: Solutions like these are great because they are easy to follow. The solutions with loops, stacks, etc. are nice but harder to inspect than this one.

All this needs is a line or two to trim it down to a fixed alphabet (just [a-zA-Z] characters?).

Comment: You'd have to remove the spaces from the string first, otherwise palindrome's like "a man a plan a canal panama" wouldn't check properly.

Comment: In whatever language that is, why not just do  "return StringReverse(originalString)==originalString"

Comment: don't forget that one usually want's an case-insensitive string comparison!

Comment: it doesn't check if the palindrome is words, like "no means no".

Comment: I'm surprised this one is voted up so much considering it's wrong. As people have pointed out, it will not work for all palindromes, specifically with punctuation etc. The wisdom of crowds eh..

Comment: With a strict definition of a palindrome, however, this works exactly. The definition does not specify what "reading the same in either direction" means, and as such, a strict character for character comparison, which this is, is the most simple algorithm.

Answer (score 24):

**C#** in-place algorithm. Any preprocessing, like case insensitivity or stripping of whitespace and punctuation should be done before passing to this function.

```
boolean IsPalindrome(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != s[s.Length - 1 - i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

**Edit:** removed unnecessary "`+1`" in loop condition and spent the saved comparison on removing the redundant Length comparison. Thanks to the commenters!

Comment: I think you have a benign fencepost error there.

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit more specific there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about the s.Length / 2 + 1. It looks like the plus one will only ever make you check the middle letter in an odd length word, or the middle two letters in an even length word twice.

Comment: I've agreed with Imbue. Consider s = 'aba': s.Length / 2 == 1 -> i<=1 -> s[1] = s[3 - 1 - 1] (unnecessary comparison of middle letter with itself) or s = 'ab': s.Length / 2 == 1 -> i <= 1 -> s[1] = s[2 - 1 - 1] (letters checked twice unnecessary).

Comment: Additionally It is unclear whether an empty string is a palindrome.

Comment: re fencepost: d'oh, you're right of course! re empty string: `"".reverse() == ""`, so I'm quite sure that the empty string is a palindrome, as is every one-character string.

Comment: The `if (s.Length < 2)` is redundant. s.Length /2 == 0 if s.Length < 2 therefore i < 0 == false -> return true.

Answer (score 15):

C#: LINQ

```
var str = "a b a";
var test = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(str.ToCharArray(), 
           str.ToCharArray().Reverse());
```

Comment: Nice! but a bit of an overkill IMHO

Answer (score 14):

A more Ruby-style rewrite of [Hal's Ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002/how-to-check-if-the-given-string-is-palindrome#52328):

```
class String
  def palindrome?
    (test = gsub(/[^A-Za-z]/, '').downcase) == test.reverse
  end
end
```

Now you can call `palindrome?` on any string.

Answer (score 12):

Unoptimized Python:

```
>>> def is_palindrome(s):
...     return s == s[::-1]
```

Comment: I try. I often fail, but not this time, it would seem. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you could edit your answer to add in the whitespace and punctuation handling from my answer below but then it wouldn't be so pretty.  :-)

Comment: A one line function like that can be done as a lambda:
is_palindrome=lambda s:s == s[::-1]

Comment: Why make a function at all, when you can just do "is_palindrome = s == s[::-1]"? ;)

Comment: Anders Sandvig: for readability? And perhaps ease of maintenance in case we decide to ignore whitespace and punctuation as Dave Webb has done?

Comment: It doesn't work for sequences that doesn't support extended slicing. http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/slicings.html . But `def ispal(iterable): s = list(iterable); return s == s[::-1]` does work.

Answer (score 11):

Java solution:

```
public class QuickTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    check("AmanaplanacanalPanama".toLowerCase());
    check("Hello World".toLowerCase());
}

public static void check(String aString) {
    System.out.print(aString + ": ");
    char[] chars = aString.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = (chars.length - 1); i < (chars.length / 2); i++, j--) {
        if (chars[i] != chars[j]) {
            System.out.println("Not a palindrome!");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Found a palindrome!");
}
```

}

Comment: Is this optimized , by my guess the running time is 0(N)

Answer (score 10):

Using a good data structure usually helps impress the professor:

Push half the chars onto a stack (Length / 2).
Pop and compare each char until the first unmatch.
If the stack has zero elements: palindrome.
*in the case of a string with an odd Length, throw out the middle char.

Comment: Using O(n) memory where a in-place algorithm works would probably not impress a professor

Comment: How would a Pushdown automaton know where the middle is? ;P

Comment: To answer sleeplessnerd, you'd use a freelist. Essentially it's a 2nd stack that shrinks as the first one grows. Though that would probably be overkill on logic tests for if stack1.length() == 2.length()

Answer (score 10):

C in the house. (not sure if you didn't want a C example here)

```
bool IsPalindrome(char *s)
{
    int  i,d;
    int  length = strlen(s);
    char cf, cb;

    for(i=0, d=length-1 ; i < length && d >= 0 ; i++ , d--)
    {
        while(cf= toupper(s[i]), (cf < 'A' || cf >'Z') && i < length-1)i++;
        while(cb= toupper(s[d]), (cb < 'A' || cb >'Z') && d > 0       )d--;
        if(cf != cb && cf >= 'A' && cf <= 'Z' && cb >= 'A' && cb <='Z')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That will return true for "racecar", "Racecar", "race car", "racecar ", and "RaCe cAr".  It would be easy to modify to include symbols or spaces as well, but I figure it's more useful to only count letters(and ignore case).  This works for all palindromes I've found in the answers here, and I've been unable to trick it into false negatives/positives.

Also, if you don't like bool in a "C" program, it could obviously return int, with return 1 and return 0 for true and false respectively.

Comment: ofcourse, always loves the c solutions :)

Comment: I think you can optimize the exit condition to:
    for( ...; d>=i; ... )
It will cut the execution time by half

Answer (score 8):

Here's a python way. Note: this isn't really that "pythonic" but it demonstrates the algorithm.

```
def IsPalindromeString(n):
    myLen = len(n)
    i = 0
    while i <= myLen/2:
        if n[i] != n[myLen-1-i]:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

Comment: If you don't like: `ispalindrome = lamdba s: s == s[::-1]` then you could use `def ispalindrome(seq): return all(seq[i] == seq[-i-1] for i in range(len(seq) // 2))`

Comment: btw, CamelCase is not recommended for function and local variable names. See 'Style Guide for Python Code' http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 6):

```
Delphi

function IsPalindrome(const s: string): boolean;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  j := Length(s);
  for i := 1 to Length(s) div 2 do begin
    if s[i] <> s[j] then
      Exit;
    Dec(j);
  end;
  Result := true;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: from the comments:

```
bool palindrome(std::string const& s) 
{ 
  return std::equal(s.begin(), s.end(), s.rbegin()); 
}
```

---

The c++ way.

My naive implementation using the elegant iterators. In reality, you would probably check
and stop once your forward iterator has past the halfway mark to your string.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool palindrome(string foo)
{
    string::iterator front;
    string::reverse_iterator back;
    bool is_palindrome = true;
    for(front = foo.begin(), back = foo.rbegin();
        is_palindrome && front!= foo.end() && back != foo.rend();
        ++front, ++back
        )
    {
        if(*front != *back)
            is_palindrome = false;
    }
    return is_palindrome;
}
int main()
{
    string a = "hi there", b = "laval";

    cout << "String a: \"" << a << "\" is " << ((palindrome(a))? "" : "not ") << "a palindrome." <<endl;
    cout << "String b: \"" << b << "\" is " << ((palindrome(b))? "" : "not ") << "a palindrome." <<endl;

}
```

Comment: Or perhaps:

bool palindrome(string foo)
{
    return std::equal(foo.begin(), foo.end(), foo.rbegin());
}

Comment: Oh, and string should be passed as a reference: bool palindrome(string const& foo) { return std::equal(foo.begin(), foo.end(), foo.rbegin()); }

Comment: I like that, much more elegant.

Comment: **love** the std::equal() solution!

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing a lot of incorrect answers here. Any correct solution needs to ignore whitespace and punctuation (and any non-alphabetic characters actually) and needs to be case insensitive.

A few good example test cases are:

"A man, a plan, a canal, Panama."

"A Toyota's a Toyota."

"A"

""

As well as some non-palindromes.

Example solution in C# (note: empty and null strings are considered palindromes in this design, if this is not desired it's easy to change):

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string palindromeCandidate)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(palindromeCandidate))
    {
        return true;
    }
    Regex nonAlphaChars = new Regex("[^a-z0-9]");
    string alphaOnlyCandidate = nonAlphaChars.Replace(palindromeCandidate.ToLower(), "");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(alphaOnlyCandidate))
    {
        return true;
    }
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = alphaOnlyCandidate.Length - 1;
    while (rightIndex > leftIndex)
    {
        if (alphaOnlyCandidate[leftIndex] != alphaOnlyCandidate[rightIndex])
        {
            return false;
        }
        leftIndex++;
        rightIndex--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be Regex nonAlphaChars = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

So that we also take care of capitalized chars in the string

Comment: May be not..you have used ToLower....sorry I just missed it

Comment: You said: Any correct solution needs to ignore whitespace and punctuation (and any non-alphabetic characters actually) and needs to be case insensitive. What makes you think that this is true? Does anybody have a correct definition of a palindrome? Following the definition of the questionnee, I don't agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean isPalindrome(String str1) {
  //first strip out punctuation and spaces
  String stripped = str1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
  return stripped.equalsIgnoreCase((new StringBuilder(stripped)).reverse().toString());
}
```

Java version

Comment: Striktly I would not allow IgnoreCase for a palindrome.

Comment: Why not?  See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palindrome

Comment: Why not?  If case matters then "A man a plan a canal Panama" isn't a palindrome.

Comment: Who says "A man a plan a canal Panama" is a palindrome? In my opinion, this does not read the same as "amanap lanac a nalp a nam a"

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution in c#

```
static bool isPalindrome(string s)
{
    string allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"+
        "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string compareString = String.Empty;
    string rev = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];

        if (allowedChars.IndexOf(c) > -1)
        {
            compareString += c;
        }
    }


    for (int i = compareString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char c = compareString[i];
        rev += c;
    }

    return rev.Equals(compareString, 
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution, without using a strrev. Written in C#, but it will work in any language that has a string length function.

```
private static bool Pal(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[s.Length - 1 - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: replace `i < s.Length` by `i < s.Length / 2`

Comment: Doesn't work because it doesn't ignore whitespace or punctuation.

Comment: it will work in any language that has a string length function. -> that's not really true. s[i] does not compile in java :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Python version that deals with different cases, punctuation and whitespace.

```
import string

def is_palindrome(palindrome):
    letters = palindrome.translate(string.maketrans("",""),
                  string.whitespace + string.punctuation).lower()
    return letters == letters[::-1]
```

**Edit:** Shamelessly stole from [Blair Conrad's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002/how-to-check-if-the-given-string-is-palindrome#52023) neater answer to remove the slightly clumsy list processing from my previous version.

Answer (score 3):

An obfuscated C version:

```
int IsPalindrome (char *s)
{
  char*a,*b,c=0;
  for(a=b=s;a<=b;c=(c?c==1?c=(*a&~32)-65>25u?*++a,1:2:c==2?(*--b&~32)-65<26u?3:2:c==3?(*b-65&~32)-(*a-65&~32)?*(b=s=0,a),4:*++a,1:0:*++b?0:1));
  return s!=0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### C++

```
std::string a = "god";
std::string b = "lol";

std::cout << (std::string(a.rbegin(), a.rend()) == a) << " " 
          << (std::string(b.rbegin(), b.rend()) == b);
```

### Bash

```
function ispalin { [ "$( echo -n $1 | tac -rs . )" = "$1" ]; }
echo "$(ispalin god && echo yes || echo no), $(ispalin lol && echo yes || echo no)"
```

### Gnu Awk

```
/* obvious solution */
function ispalin(cand, i) { 
    for(i=0; i<length(cand)/2; i++) 
        if(substr(cand, length(cand)-i, 1) != substr(cand, i+1, 1)) 
            return 0; 
    return 1; 
}

/* not so obvious solution. cough cough */
{ 
    orig = $0;
    while($0) { 
        stuff = stuff gensub(/^.*(.)$/, "\\1", 1); 
        $0 = gensub(/^(.*).$/, "\\1", 1); 
    }
    print (stuff == orig); 
}
```

### Haskell

Some brain dead way doing it in Haskell

```
ispalin :: [Char] -> Bool
ispalin a = a == (let xi (y:my) = (xi my) ++ [y]; xi [] = [] in \x -> xi x) a
```

### Plain English

`"Just reverse the string and if it is the same as before, it's a palindrome"`

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby:

```
class String
    def is_palindrome?
        letters_only = gsub(/\W/,'').downcase
        letters_only == letters_only.reverse
    end
end

puts 'abc'.is_palindrome? # => false
puts 'aba'.is_palindrome? # => true
puts "Madam, I'm Adam.".is_palindrome? # => true
```

Answer (score 2):

This Java code should work inside a **boolean** method:

**Note**: You only need to check the first half of the characters with the back half, otherwise you are overlapping and doubling the amount of checks that need to be made.

```
private static boolean doPal(String test) {
    for(int i = 0; i < test.length() / 2; i++) {
        if(test.charAt(i) != test.charAt(test.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Three versions in Smalltalk, from dumbest to correct.

---

In Smalltalk, `=` is the comparison operator:

```
isPalindrome: aString
    "Dumbest."
    ^ aString reverse = aString
```

---

The message `#translateToLowercase` returns the string as lowercase:

```
isPalindrome: aString
    "Case insensitive"
    |lowercase|
    lowercase := aString translateToLowercase.
    ^ lowercase reverse = lowercase
```

---

And in Smalltalk, strings are part of the `Collection` framework, you can use the message `#select:thenCollect:`, so here's the last version:

```
isPalindrome: aString
    "Case insensitive and keeping only alphabetic chars
    (blanks & punctuation insensitive)."
    |lowercaseLetters|
    lowercaseLetters := aString
        select: [:char | char isAlphabetic]
        thenCollect: [:char | char asLowercase]. 
    ^ lowercaseLetters reverse = lowercaseLetters
```

Answer (score 2):

Another C++ one. Optimized for speed and size.

`bool is_palindrome(const std::string& candidate) {
    for(std::string::const_iterator left = candidate.begin(), right = candidate.end(); left < --right ; ++left)
        if (*left != *right)
            return false;
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 2):

**Lisp:**

```
(defun palindrome(x) (string= x (reverse x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the above C++ solutions, there was some problems.

One solution was inefficient because it passed an std::string by copy, and because it iterated over all the chars, instead of comparing only half the chars. Then, even when discovering the string was not a palindrome, it continued the loop, waiting its end before reporting "false".

The other was better, with a very small function, whose problem was that it was not able to test anything else than std::string. In C++, it is easy to extend an algorithm to a whole bunch of similar objects. By templating its std::string into "T", it would have worked on both std::string, std::wstring, std::vector and std::deque. But without major modification because of the use of the operator <, the std::list was out of its scope.

My own solutions try to show that a C++ solution won't stop at working on the exact current type, but will strive to work an *anything* that behaves the same way, no matter the type. For example, I could apply my palindrome tests on std::string, on vector of int or on list of "Anything" as long as Anything was comparable through its operator = (build in types, as well as classes).

Note that the template can even be extended with an optional type that can be used to compare the data. For example, if you want to compare in a case insensitive way, or even compare similar characters (like è, é, ë, ê and e).

Like king Leonidas would have said: *"Templates ? This is C++ !!!"*

So, in C++, there are at least 3 major ways to do it, each one leading to the other:

### Solution A: In a c-like way

The problem is that until C++0X, we can't consider the std::string array of chars as contiguous, so we must "cheat" and retrieve the c_str() property. As we are using it in a read-only fashion, it should be ok...

---

```
bool isPalindromeA(const std::string & p_strText)
{
   if(p_strText.length() < 2) return true ;
   const char * pStart = p_strText.c_str() ;             
   const char * pEnd = pStart + p_strText.length() - 1 ; 

   for(; pStart < pEnd; ++pStart, --pEnd)
   {
      if(*pStart != *pEnd)
      {
         return false ;
      }
   }

   return true ;
}
```

---

### Solution B: A more "C++" version

Now, we'll try to apply the same solution, but to any C++ container with random access to its items through operator []. For example, any std::basic_string, std::vector, std::deque, etc. Operator [] is constant access for those containers, so we won't lose undue speed.

---

```
template <typename T>
bool isPalindromeB(const T & p_aText)
{
   if(p_aText.empty()) return true ;
   typename T::size_type iStart = 0 ;
   typename T::size_type iEnd = p_aText.size() - 1 ;

   for(; iStart < iEnd; ++iStart, --iEnd)
   {
      if(p_aText[iStart] != p_aText[iEnd])
      {
         return false ;
      }
   }

   return true ;
}
```

---

### Solution C: Template powah !

It will work with almost any unordered STL-like container with bidirectional iterators
For example, any std::basic_string, std::vector, std::deque, std::list, etc.
So, this function can be applied on all STL-like containers with the following conditions:
1 - T is a container with bidirectional iterator
2 - T's iterator points to a comparable type (through operator =)

---

```
template <typename T>
bool isPalindromeC(const T & p_aText)
{
   if(p_aText.empty()) return true ;
   typename T::const_iterator pStart = p_aText.begin() ;
   typename T::const_iterator pEnd = p_aText.end() ;
   --pEnd ;

   while(true)
   {
      if(*pStart != *pEnd)
      {
         return false ;
      }

      if((pStart == pEnd) || (++pStart == pEnd))
      {
         return true ;
      }

      --pEnd ;
   }
}
```

---

Comment: Fancy. How big will the string have to be so that this method is faster than comparing with the reverse?

Comment: If you don't have the reverse, then you have to allocate and then create it by copying the data. I guess that comparing the reverse is always slower, but for curiosity's sake, I'm interested in any "comparing the reverse" implementation.

Comment: None of these work because you don't ignore whitespace or punctuation.

Comment: @John Dibling: Even if I handled punctuation and whitespace, it wouldn't work in Unicode on Linux because of UTF-8. The aim of this code is show C++ code, not produce an industrial-strength function.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Java solution:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String testString) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(testString);
    String reverseString = sb.reverse().toString();

    if(testString.equalsIgnoreCase(reverseString)) {
        return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it. I guess the key is to do it in the most efficient way possible (without looping the string). I would do it as a char array which can be reversed easily (using C#).

```
string mystring = "abracadabra";

char[] str = mystring.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(str);
string revstring = new string(str);

if (mystring.equals(revstring))
{
    Console.WriteLine("String is a Palindrome");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, converting to lowercase and stripping everything not alphabetic:

```
def isPalindrome( string )
    ( test = string.downcase.gsub( /[^a-z]/, '' ) ) == test.reverse
end
```

But that feels like cheating, right? No pointers or anything! So here's a C version too, but without the lowercase and character stripping goodness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isPalindrome( char * string )
{
    char * i = string;
    char * p = string;
    while ( *++i ); while ( i > p && *p++ == *--i );
    return i <= p && *i++ == *--p;
}
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s <word>\n", argv[0] );
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf( stdout, "%s\n", isPalindrome( argv[1] ) ? "yes" : "no" );
    return 0;
}
```

Well, that was fun - do I get the job ;^)

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
sub is_palindrome($)
{
  $s = lc(shift); # ignore case
  $s =~ s/\W+//g; # consider only letters, digits, and '_'
  $s eq reverse $s;
}
```

It ignores case and strips non-alphanumeric characters (it locale- and unicode- neutral).

Answer (score 1):

Using Java, using [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) String Utils:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String phrase) {
  phrase = phrase.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
  return StringUtils.reverse(phrase).equals(phrase);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for a programming challenge, here's a snippet of my Haskell:

```
isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome n = (n == reverse n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
if s == s[::-1]: return True
```

Java:

```
if (s.Equals(s.Reverse())) { return true; }
```

PHP:

```
if (s == strrev(s)) return true;
```

Perl:

```
if (s == reverse(s)) { return true; }
```

Erlang:

```
string:equal(S, lists:reverse(S)).
```

Comment: Hmm … what happens if this is `false`? No return value? Why the `if`s in the first place? Simply returning the expression works just as well.

Comment: Java Strings don't have a .Reverse() method (nor is .equals() capitalized).

Comment: None of this does't works, there's not a single validation... try this: "A Santa at NASA"

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
sub is_palindrome {
    my $s = lc shift; # normalize case
    $s =~ s/\W//g;    # strip non-word characters
    return $s eq reverse $s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

c++:

```
bool is_palindrome(const string &s)
{
    return equal( s.begin(), s.begin()+s.length()/2, s.rbegin());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2c.  Avoids overhead of full string reversal everytime, taking advantage of shortcircuiting to return as soon as the nature of the string is determined.  Yes, you should condition your string first, but IMO that's the job of another function.

**In C#**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests if a string is a palindrome
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsPalindrome(this String str)
    {
        if (str.Length == 0) return false;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < str.Length / 2)
            if (str[index] != str[str.Length - ++index]) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Prolog**

```
palindrome(B, R) :-
palindrome(B, R, []).

palindrome([], R, R).
palindrome([X|B], [X|R], T) :-
palindrome(B, R, [X|T]).
```

Comment: shouldn't it be with only one argument? something like:
palindrome(L) :- palindrome(L, []).
palindrome(L, L).
palindrome([_, L], L).
palindrome([X|R], L) :- palindrome(R, [X|L]).

Comment: @Kru how does it handle palindromes like "121"?

Comment: typing mistake... replace `palindrome([_,L],L).` by `palindrome([_|L],L).`
So, `palindrome("121", []) -> palindrome("21", "1") = palindrome([2|"1"], "1")` which matches the corrected fact.

Answer (score 1):

Erlang is awesome

```
palindrome(L) -> palindrome(L,[]).

palindrome([],_) -> false;
palindrome([_|[]],[]) -> true;
palindrome([_|L],L) -> true;
palindrome(L,L) -> true;
palindrome([H|T], Acc) -> palindrome(T, [H|Acc]).
```

Answer (score 1):

No solution using JavaScript yet?

```
function palindrome(s) {
  var l = 0, r = s.length - 1;
  while (l < r) if (s.charAt(left++) !== s.charAt(r--)) return false;
  return true
}
```

Comment: Most Javascript examples use `s === s.split('').reverse().join('')` ... kudos for efficiency :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple **JavaScript** solution. Run code snippet for demo.

```js
function checkPalindrome(line){
      reverse_line=line.split("").reverse().join("");
      return line==reverse_line;
  }
alert("checkPalindrome(radar): "+checkPalindrome("radar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one from Delphi, which I think is a little more rigorous than the other Delphi example submitted.  This can easily turn into a golfing match, but I've tried to make mine readable.

*Edit0: I was curious about the performance characteristics, so I did a little test.  On my machine, I ran this function against a 60 character string 50 million times, and it took 5 seconds.*

```
function TForm1.IsPalindrome(txt: string): boolean;
var
  i, halfway, len : integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  len := Length(txt);

  {
  special cases:
  an empty string is *never* a palindrome
  a 1-character string is *always* a palindrome
  }
  case len of
    0 : Result := False;
    1 : Result := True;
    else begin
      halfway := Round((len/2) - (1/2));  //if odd, round down to get 1/2way pt

      //scan half of our string, make sure it is mirrored on the other half
      for i := 1 to halfway do begin
        if txt[i] <> txt[len-(i-1)] then begin
          Result := False;
          Break;
        end;  //if we found a non-mirrored character
      end;  //for 1st half of string
    end;  //else not a special case
  end;  //case
end;
```

And here is the same thing, in C#, except that I've left it with multiple exit points, which I don't like.

```
private bool IsPalindrome(string txt) {
  int len = txt.Length;

  /*
  Special cases:
  An empty string is *never* a palindrome
  A 1-character string is *always* a palindrome
  */    
  switch (len) {
    case 0: return false;
    case 1: return true;
  }  //switch
  int halfway = (len / 2);

  //scan half of our string, make sure it is mirrored on the other half
  for (int i = 0; i < halfway; ++i) {
    if (txt.Substring(i,1) != txt.Substring(len - i - 1,1)) {
      return false;
    }  //if
  }  //for
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The only difference is that my code treats empty string as a palindrome. That is by design.

Answer (score 0):

C#3 - This returns false as soon as a char counted from the beginning fails to match its equivalent at the end:

```
static bool IsPalindrome(this string input)
{
    char[] letters = input.ToUpper().ToCharArray();

    int i = 0;
    while( i < letters.Length / 2 )
        if( letters[i] != letters[letters.Length - ++i] )
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there an off-by-one error here?  The first comparison is between letters[0] and letters[letters.Length-0], shouldn't the latter be letter[letters.Length-1]?

Answer (score 0):

If we're looking for numbers and simple words, many correct answers have been given.

However, if we're looking for what we generally see as palindromes in written language (e.g., "A dog, a panic, in a pagoda!"), the correct answer would be to iterate starting from both ends of the sentence, *skipping non-alphanumeric characters individually*, and returning false if any mismatches are found.

```
i = 0; j = length-1;

while( true ) {
  while( i < j && !is_alphanumeric( str[i] ) ) i++;
  while( i < j && !is_alphanumeric( str[j] ) ) j--;

  if( i >= j ) return true;

  if( tolower(string[i]) != tolower(string[j]) ) return false;
  i++; j--;
}
```

Of course, stripping out non-valid characters, reversing the resulting string and comparing it to the original one also works. It comes down to what type of language you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml:

```
let rec palindrome s =
  s = (tailrev s)
```

[source](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~lhuang3/cse399-python/handouts/ocaml.ppt)

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean IsPalindrome(string s) {
return s = s.Reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a *single* solution on here which takes into account that a palindrome can also be based on word units, not just character units.

Which means that none of the given solutions return true for palindromes like "Girl, bathing on Bikini, eyeing boy, sees boy eyeing bikini on bathing girl".

Here's a hacked together version in C#. I'm sure it doesn't need the regexes, but it does work just as well with the above bikini palindrome as it does with "A man, a plan, a canal-Panama!".

```
    static bool IsPalindrome(string text)
    {
        bool isPalindrome = IsCharacterPalindrome(text);
        if (!isPalindrome)
        {
            isPalindrome = IsPhrasePalindrome(text);
        }
        return isPalindrome;
    }

    static bool IsCharacterPalindrome(string text)
    {
        String clean = Regex.Replace(text.ToLower(), "[^A-z0-9]", String.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        bool isPalindrome = false;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clean) && clean.Length > 1)
        {
            isPalindrome = true;
            for (int i = 0, count = clean.Length / 2 + 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (clean[i] != clean[clean.Length - 1 - i])
                {
                    isPalindrome = false; break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isPalindrome;
    }

    static bool IsPhrasePalindrome(string text)
    {
        bool isPalindrome = false;
        String clean = Regex.Replace(text.ToLower(), @"[^A-z0-9\s]", " ", RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
        String[] words = Regex.Split(clean, @"\s+");
        if (words.Length > 1)
        {
            isPalindrome = true;
            for (int i = 0, count = words.Length / 2 + 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (words[i] != words[words.Length - 1 - i])
                {
                    isPalindrome = false; break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isPalindrome;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any recursion yet, so here goes...

```
import re

r = re.compile("[^0-9a-zA-Z]")

def is_pal(s):

    def inner_pal(s):
        if len(s) == 0:
            return True
        elif s[0] == s[-1]:
            return inner_pal(s[1:-1])
        else:
            return False

    r = re.compile("[^0-9a-zA-Z]")
    return inner_pal(r.sub("", s).lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all good, but is there a way to do better algorithmically? I was once asked in a interview to recognize a palindrome in linear time and *constant space*.

I couldn't think of anything then and I still can't.

(If it helps, I asked the interviewer what the answer was. He said you can construct a pair of hash functions such that they hash a given string to the same value if and only if that string is a palindrome. I have no idea how you would actually make this pair of functions.)

Answer (score 0):

The solutions which strip out any chars that don't fall between A-Z or a-z are very English centric. Letters with diacritics such as à or é would be stripped!

According to Wikipedia:

> The treatment of diacritics varies. In languages such as Czech and Spanish, letters with diacritics or accents (except tildes) are not given a separate place in the alphabet, and thus preserve the palindrome whether or not the repeated letter has an ornamentation. However, in Swedish and other Nordic languages, A and A with a ring (å) are distinct letters and must be mirrored exactly to be considered a true palindrome.

So to cover many other languages it would be better to use collation to convert diacritical marks to their equivalent non diacritic or leave alone as appropriate and then strip whitespace and punctuation only before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

```
set l = index of left most character in word
set r = index of right most character in word

loop while(l < r)
begin
  if letter at l does not equal letter at r
    word is not palindrome
  else
     increase l and decrease r
end
word is palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient C++ version:

```
template< typename Iterator >
bool is_palindrome( Iterator first, Iterator last, std::locale const& loc = std::locale("") )
{
    if ( first == last )
        return true;

    for( --last; first < last; ++first, --last )
    {
        while( ! std::isalnum( *first, loc ) && first < last )
            ++first;
        while( ! std::isalnum( *last, loc ) && first < last )
            --last;
        if ( std::tolower( *first, loc ) != std::tolower( *last, loc ) )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more Perl versions, neither of which uses `reverse`.  Both use the basic algorithm of comparing the first character of the string to the last, then discarding them and repeating the test, but they use different methods of getting at the individual characters (the first peels them off one at a time with a regex, the second `split`s the string into an array of characters).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @strings = ("A man, a plan, a canal, Panama.", "A Toyota's a Toyota.", 
               "A", "", "As well as some non-palindromes.");

for my $string (@strings) {
  print is_palindrome($string)  ? "'$string' is a palindrome (1)\n"
                                : "'$string' is not a palindrome (1)\n";
  print is_palindrome2($string) ? "'$string' is a palindrome (2)\n"
                                : "'$string' is not a palindrome (2)\n";
} 

sub is_palindrome {
  my $str = lc shift;
  $str =~ tr/a-z//cd;

  while ($str =~ s/^(.)(.*)(.)$/\2/) {
    return unless $1 eq $3;
  }

  return 1;
} 

sub is_palindrome2 {
  my $str = lc shift;
  $str =~ tr/a-z//cd;
  my @chars = split '', $str;

  while (@chars && shift @chars eq pop @chars) {};

  return scalar @chars <= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy mode in C#, only using Base Class Libraries

Edit: just saw someone did Array.Reverse also

```
public bool IsPalindrome(string s)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                else
                {
                    char[] t = s.ToCharArray();
                    Array.Reverse(t);
                    string u = new string(t);
                    if (s.ToLower() == u.ToLower())
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another for C# that I used when doing a sample server control. It can be found in the book ASP.NET 3.5 Step by Step (MS Press). It's two methods, one to strip non-alphanumerics, and another to check for a palindrome.

```
protected string StripNonAlphanumerics(string str)
{
    string strStripped = (String)str.Clone();
    if (str != null)
    {
        char[] rgc = strStripped.ToCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in rgc)
        {
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                strStripped = strStripped.Remove(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return strStripped;
}
protected bool CheckForPalindrome()
{
    if (this.Text != null)
    {
        String strControlText = this.Text;
        String strTextToUpper = null;
        strTextToUpper = Text.ToUpper();
        strControlText =
                    this.StripNonAlphanumerics(strTextToUpper);
        char[] rgcReverse = strControlText.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(rgcReverse);
        String strReverse = new string(rgcReverse);
        if (strControlText == strReverse)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Const-correct C/C++ pointer solution. Minimal operations in loop.

```
int IsPalindrome (const char *str)
{
    const unsigned len = strlen(str);
    const char *end = &str[len-1];
    while (str < end)
        if (*str++ != *end--)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scala**

```
def pal(s:String) = Symbol(s) equals Symbol(s.reverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        string formattedString = s.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower();
        for (int i = 0; i < formattedString.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            if (formattedString[i] != formattedString[formattedString.Length - 1 - i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This method will work for sting like "Was it a rat I saw". But I feel we need to eliminate special character through Regex.

Answer (score 0):

C# Version:

Assumes MyString to be a char[], Method return after verification of the string, it ignores space and <,>, but this can be extended to ignore more, probably impleemnt a regex match of ignore list.

```
public bool IsPalindrome()
            if (MyString.Length == 0)
                return false;

            int len = MyString.Length - 1;

            int first = 0;
            int second = 0;

            for (int i = 0, j = len; i <= len / 2; i++, j--)
            {
                while (i<j && MyString[i] == ' ' || MyString[i] == ',')
                    i++;

                while(j>i && MyString[j] == ' ' || MyString[j] == ',')
                    j--;

                if ((i == len / 2) && (i == j))
                    return true;

                first = MyString[i] >= 97 && MyString[i] <= 122 ? MyString[i] - 32 : MyString[i];
                second = MyString[j] >= 97 && MyString[j] <= 122 ? MyString[j] - 32 : MyString[j];

                if (first != second)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
  }
```

Quick test cases

negative
1. ABCDA 
2. AB CBAG
3. A#$BDA
4. NULL/EMPTY

positive
1. ABCBA
2. A, man a plan a canal,,Panama
3. ABC BA
4. M
5. ACCB

let me know any thoghts/errors.

Comment: You say "ACCB" (number 5) comes back positive... is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

How about this PHP example:

```
function noitcnuf( $returnstrrevverrtsnruter, $functionnoitcnuf) {
    $returnstrrev  = "returnstrrevverrtsnruter";
    $verrtsnruter = $functionnoitcnuf;
    return (strrev ($verrtsnruter) == $functionnoitcnuf) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome( String str ) {
    int count = str.length() ;
    int i, j = count - 1 ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ) {
        if ( str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j) ) return false ;
        if ( i == j ) return true ;
        j-- ;
    }
    return true ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java APIs and additional storage:

```
public static final boolean isPalindromeWithAdditionalStorage(String string) {
    String reversed = new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
    return string.equals(reversed);
}
```

In can need an in-place method for Java:

```
public static final boolean isPalindromeInPlace(String string) {
    char[] array = string.toCharArray();
    int length = array.length-1;
    int half = Math.round(array.length/2);
    char a,b;
    for (int i=length; i>=half; i--) {
        a = array[length-i];
        b = array[i];
        if (a != b) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regular Approach:**

```
flag = True // Assume palindrome is true
for i from 0 to n/2 
 { compare element[i] and element[n-i-1] // 0 to n-1
   if not equal set flag = False
   break }
return flag
```

There is a better machine optimized method which uses XORs but has the same complexity 
**XOR approach**:

```
n = length of string
mid_element = element[n/2 +1]
for i from 0 to n
{ t_xor = element[i] xor element[i+1] }
if n is odd compare mid_element and t_xor
else check t_xor is zero
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class palindrome {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer strBuf1 = new StringBuffer("malayalam");
    StringBuffer strBuf2 = new StringBuffer("malayalam");
    strBuf2.reverse();


    System.out.println(strBuf2);
    System.out.println((strBuf1.toString()).equals(strBuf2.toString()));
    if ((strBuf1.toString()).equals(strBuf2.toString()))
        System.out.println("palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println("not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A case-insensitive, `const`-friendly version in plain C that ignores non-alphanumeric characters (e.g. whitespace / punctuation). It therefore will actually pass on classics like "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama".

```
int ispalin(const char *b)
{
    const char *e = b;
    while (*++e);
    while (--e >= b)
    {
        if (isalnum(*e))
        {
            while (*b && !isalnum(*b)) ++b;
            if (toupper(*b++) != toupper(*e)) return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The interviewer will be looking for some logic on how you will be approaching this problem:
Please consider the following java code:

1. always check if the input string is null
2. check your base cases.
3. format your string accordingly (remove anything that is not a character/digit
4. Most likely they do not want to see if you know the reverse function, and a comparison, but rather if you are able to answer the question using a loop and indexing.
5. shortcut return as soon as you know your answer and do not waste resources for nothing.

   public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

   ```
   if (s == null || s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
       return false;

   String ss = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("/[^a-z]/", "");

   for (int i = 0; i < ss.length()/2; i++) 
       if (ss.charAt(i) != ss.charAt(ss.length() - 1 - i))
           return false;
   return true;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Java with stacks.

```
public class StackPalindrome {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) throws OverFlowException,EmptyStackException{
        boolean isPal=false;
        String pal="";
        char letter;
        if (s==" ")
            return true;
        else{   
            s=s.toLowerCase();
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

            letter=s.charAt(i);

            char[] alphabet={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
            for(int j=0; j<alphabet.length;j++){
                /*removing punctuations*/
                if ((String.valueOf(letter)).equals(String.valueOf(alphabet[j]))){
                    pal +=letter;
                }

            }

        }
        int len=pal.length();
        char[] palArray=new char[len];
        for(int r=0;r<len;r++){
            palArray[r]=pal.charAt(r);
        }
        ArrayStack palStack=new ArrayStack(len);
        for(int k=0;k<palArray.length;k++){
            palStack.push(palArray[k]);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++){

            if ((palStack.topAndpop()).equals(palArray[i]))
                isPal=true;
            else 
                isPal=false;
        }
    return isPal;
    }
}
public static void main (String args[]) throws EmptyStackException,OverFlowException{

    StackPalindrome s=new StackPalindrome();
    System.out.println(s.isPalindrome("“Ma,” Jerome raps pot top, “Spare more jam!”"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Single program for Both String or Integer to check palindrome

//In java with out using string functions like reverse and equals method also and display matching characters also

package com.practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pallindrome {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0,j=0,k,count=0;
        String input,temp;
        System.out.println("Enter the String or Integer");
        input=sc.nextLine();
        temp=input;
        k=temp.length()-1;
        for(i=0;i<=input.length()-1;i++) {
            if(input.charAt(j)==temp.charAt(k)) {
                count++;
            }
            //For matching characters
            j++;
            k--;
        }
                System.out.println("Matching Characters = "+count);

        if(count==input.length()) {
            System.out.println("It's a pallindrome");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("It's not a pallindrome");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
}
```

for versions of Java earlier than 1.5,

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return str.equals(new StringBuffer().append(str).reverse().toString());
}
```

or

```
public static boolean istPalindrom(char[] word){
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = word.length - 1;
    while (i2 > i1) {
        if (word[i1] != word[i2]) {
            return false;
        }
        ++i1;
        --i2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// JavaScript Version.
function isPalindrome(str) { 
  str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '')
  return str.split('').reverse().join('').toUpperCase() === str.toUpperCase()       
}
```