# Java, string arrays. Checking the text if the first and last letter are same. I need to do it in regular expr

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm

I have some text , i separated the words and now I need to check each word if it starts with the same letter it ends ( example: 'teeet','teeeT,'Teeet'). How do i do that ? Here is what I've done:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = input.nextLine();

    String[] arr = text.split(" ");
    System.out.println("Display all words in a string: ");
    for ( String ss : arr) {

        // What now ?
    }
```

I need to do it in regular expression

Comment: Scanner already splits by space if you use `next()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex:

```
if (str.matches("(?i)(.).*\\1"))
```

Comment: But how do I do the same but if the first letter is uppercase and last is lowercase ? So 'Teeet' and 'teeeT' would also be true ?

Comment: I've added the "ignore case" switch `(?i)` to the regex - it will work as you need now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) and [`String#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29):

```
char first = ss.charAt(0);
char last  = ss.charAt(ss.length() - 1);
```

Now compare them.

I recommend you to always check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) before asking, it will contain the answer for questions like this.

---

For your edit, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486905/java-regex-find-first-and-last-characters) by @Bohemian:

> you can determine using regex if the first and last characters are the
>   same:
>
> `str.matches("(.).*\\1")`

Answer (score 3):

```
if (ss.charAt(0) == ss.charAt(s.length() - 1)) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

public Test() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = input.nextLine();

    String[] arr = text.split(" ");
    System.out.println("Display all words in a string: ");
    for (String ss : arr) {
        System.out.println("testing word:" + ss);
        String firstLetter = ss.substring(0, 1);
        String lastLetter = ss.substring(ss.length() - 1, ss.length());
        boolean firstEqualsLast = firstLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetter);
        System.out.println("first char equals last char=" + firstEqualsLast);
    }
}
}
```