# Python regular expression for repeating punctuation and symbols

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that will match repeating (more than one) punctuation and symbols. Basically all repeating non-alphanumeric and non-whitespace characters such as ..., ???, !!!, ###, @@@, +++ and etc. It must be the same character that's repeated, so not a sequence like "!?@".

I had tried [^\s\w]+ and while that covers all off the !!!, ???, $$$ cases, but that gives me more than what I want since it will also match "!?@".

Can someone enlighten me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern:

```
([.\?#@+,<>%~`!$^&\(\):;])\1+
```

`\1` is referring to the first matched group, which is contents of the parentheses.

You need to extend the list of punctuations and symbols as desired.

Comment: Not supported in Python, AFAIK.

Comment: That is, `\p{P}` and `\p{S}`. The backreference part is.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

`[run for run, leadchar in re.findall(r'(([^\w\s])\2+)', yourstring)]`

Example:

```
In : teststr = "4spaces    then(*(@^#$&&&&(2((((99999****"

In : [run for run, leadchar in re.findall(r'(([^\w\s])\2+)',teststr)]
Out: ['&&&&', '((((', '****']
```

This gives you a list of the runs, excluding the 4 spaces in that string as well as sequences like '*(@^'

If that's not exactly what you want, you might edit your question with an example string and precisely what output you wanted to see.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: @Firoze Lafeer posted an answer that does everything with a single regular expression.  I'll leave this up in case anyone is interested in combining a regular expression with a filtering function, but for this problem it would be simpler and faster to use Firoze Lafeer's answer.

Answer written before I saw Firoze Lafeer's answer is below, unchanged.

A simple regular expression can't do this.  The classic pithy summary is "regular expressions can't count".  Discussion here:

[How to check that a string is a palindrome using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233243/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-a-palindrome-using-regular-expressions)

For a Python solution I would recommend combining a regular expression with a little bit of Python code.  The regular expression throws out everything that isn't a run of some sort of punctuation, and then the Python code checks to throw out false matches (matches that are runs of punctuation but not all the same character).

```
import re
import string

# Character class to match punctuation.  The dash ('-') is special
# in character classes, so put a backslash in front of it to make
# it just a literal dash.
_char_class_punct = "[" + re.escape(string.punctuation) + "]"

# Pattern: a punctuation character followed by one or more punctuation characters.
# Thus, a run of two or more punctuation characters.
_pat_punct_run = re.compile(_char_class_punct + _char_class_punct + '+')

def all_same(seq, basis_case=True):
    itr = iter(seq)
    try:
        first = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        return basis_case
    return all(x == first for x in itr)

def find_all_punct_runs(text):
    return [s for s in _pat_punct_run.findall(text) if all_same(s, False)]


# alternate version of find_all_punct_runs() using re.finditer()
def find_all_punct_runs(text):
    return (s for s in (m.group(0) for m in _pat_punct_run.finditer(text)) if all_same(s, False))
```

I wrote `all_same()` the way I did so that it will work just as well on an iterator as on a string.  The Python built-in `all()` returns `True` for an empty sequence, which is not what we want for this particular use of `all_same()`, so I made an argument for the basis case desired and made it default to `True` to match the behavior of `all()`.

This does as much of the work as possible using the internals of Python (the regular expression engine or `all()`) so it should be pretty fast.  For large input texts you might want to rewrite `find_all_punct_runs()` to use `re.finditer()` instead of `re.findall()`.  I gave an example.  The example also returns a generator expression rather than a list.  You can always force it to make a list:

```
lst = list(find_all_punct_runs(text))
```

Comment: `-` and `[` (not sure for Python) and `]` are special in character class, so is `^` if at beginning.

Comment: Try `re.escape(string.punctuation)` instead. That works. (Confirmation that it is correct: `all(re.match('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), letter) for letter in string.punctuation) == True`.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Wow, that's so much better.  It's obvious what it's doing and I don't need to worry about whether I got it right.

Comment: @nhahtdh: thanks for pointing that out.  I thought about `^`, and it's not magic unless it's at the beginning.  I thought about `[`, and inside a character class it's just another character in the class.  But I failed to consider `]` and that meant my pattern wasn't correct.  As suggested by Chris Morgan, the proper thing to do is just call `re.escape()` which will handle everything!

Comment: Regex in most of the modern language are not regular language in the strictest sense. Backreference can be used for the purpose of checking for repetition of a captured token.

Comment: I played around with backreferences in Python regular expression matching, just now, in response to your comment.  I found that it fails to check that all the characters are identical; I think the backreference is to the character class, and the repeated backreference just checks to see if the character class keeps matching.  So I can't think of any better answer than what I gave: use regular expressions to find runs of punctuation, then use a function to filter only the runs of the same character.

Comment: @steveha, not sure what you mean? See my answer as example.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer -- What I tried didn't work.  Your answer does work.  I just learned something about regular expressions in Python, and I thank you for that.  I'll edit my answer to mention yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
>>> st='non-whitespace characters such as ..., ???, !!!, ###, @@@, +++ and' 
>>> reg=r'(([.?#@+])\2{2,})'
>>> print [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(reg,st)]
```

or

```
>>> print [g for g,l in re.findall(reg, st)]
```

Either one prints:

```
['...', '???', '###', '@@@', '+++']
```