# Python: Find and print previous element

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text (just an example): `</i>5 <i></i><span class`

I'd like to remove this space, so I tried:

```
re.sub(r'</i>.* <i></i><span class', '</i>%02d<i></i><span class' %, text)
```

But this did not work. How can I catch the "thing" which is found in "`.*`"? `%02d` is obviously incorrect...

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Requisite link to another post about [parsing HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418413)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capturing group:

```
re.sub(r'</i>(.*) <i></i><span class', r'</i>\1<i></i><span class', text)
```

This capturing group, `(.*)`, captures the "5", and it is placed in the `\1` in the replacement text. Note the presence of `r` before the second string: that tells Python it's a raw string ([see here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more details)

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned, a capturing group is what you need. To elaborate further:

Round brackets capture whatever it is that they match to. This is called a 'capturing group', and a 'backreference' is created to whatever is caught. Each subsequent backreference can be referred to by \1.  So:

```
(.)b\1
```

matches 'aba' and 'mnm', but not 'abc'.

Similarly,

```
(.)(.)b\1\2
```

matches 'abbab', 'xybxy'

and

```
(.)(.)b\2\1
```

matches 'abbba', 'xybyx'

This can be then used to check a palindrome (Not that it's advised, [regex's cannot match palindromes of unspecified length limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247933/792238)):

```
(.?)(.)(.)\3?\2\1
```

is a regex which will match a palindrome of length 3 or less.