# Finding palindrome using regex

Tags: regex, perl, palindrome

This question comes in an attempt to understand one of the answer in : **[How to check that a string is a palindrome using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233243/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-a-palindrome-using-regular-expressions)**

Answer given by *Markus Jarderot* is :

```
/^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$/
```

Can someone please explain, whats exactly happening here....i need to do similar in `Perl`, but not able to understand this solution!!!

PS : I am not very good in perl so please go easy ....and also "this can't be considered a regular expression if you want to be strict" - i read this line, so *i am aware that this not regex strictly*

Comment: Re "i need to do similar in perl", That is Perl.

Comment: Perl regex grammar is described in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: See this explanation of Perl recursive regular expressions: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html

Comment: [`perldoc perlretut` - Recursive Patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Recursive-patterns)

Comment: Just FYI, you don't have to use a regex to check if a string is palindromic. The simple case is a one-liner that can be readily seasoned to taste: `sub is_palindromic { $_[0] eq reverse $_[0] }`

Comment: Not sure this regex works as a palindrome checker.

If I'm reading it right, "hih" will match "hiih" will not.

Comment: @Zaid : i agree, even `reverse` would be a better option,....but m not the one taking decisions!! :)

Comment: @ikegami : right.. i do mess up PERL,perl and Perl!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor, It wasn't a comment on the spelling. I meant that the posted code is Perl code, so the request for Perl code is ...odd. (`perl` the executable or Perl the language would both make sense.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `^` - matches beginning of string
- `(` - starts capture group #1
- `(.)` - matches any single character except a newline, save it in capture group #2
- `(?1)` - recurse = replace this group with the entire regexp capture group #1
- `\2` - matches the same thing as capture group #2. This requires the first and last characters of the string to match each other
- `|` - creates an alternative
- `.?` - optionally matches any one character that isn't a newline - This handles the end of the recursion, by matching an empty string (when the whole string is an even length) or a single character (when it's an odd length)
- `)` - ends capture group #1
- `$` - matches end of string or before a newline at the end of the string.

The recursion `(?1)` is the key. A palindrome is an empty string, a 1-character string, or a string whose first and last characters are the same and the substring between them is also a palindrome.

Comment: A 1-character string has its first and last characters the same.

Comment: recursion `(?1)` is what stumped me!! :\

Comment: @NoobEditor, It's documented under the heading "(?PARNO) (?-PARNO) (?+PARNO) (?R) (?0)"

Comment: what about even length palindromes?

Comment: @Atav32 Read the 7th bullet. It explains the even and odd cases.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to understand with this analogous function, that does the same thing for arrays:

```
sub palindrome {
  if (scalar(@_) >= 2) {
    my $first_dot = shift;
    my $slash_two = pop;
    return $first_dot eq $slash_two && palindrome(@_);
  } else {
    # zero or one items
    return 1;
  }
}

print "yes!\n" if palindrome(qw(one two three two one));
print "really?\n" if palindrome(qw(one two three two two one));
```

The `(?1)` notation is a recursive reference to the start of the first parenthesis in the regex, the `\2` is a backreference in the current recursion to the `(.)`. Those two are anchored at the start and end of 'whatever is matching at the current recursion depth', so everything else is matched at the next depth down.

---

ikegami suspects this is faster:

```
sub palindrome {
   my $next = 0;
   my %symbols;
   my $s = join '', map chr( $symbols{$_} ||= $next++ ), @_;
   return $s =~ /^((.)(?1)\2|.?)\z/s;
}
```

Comment: @ikegami, the point of this answer was not speed, but clarity, for someone who doesn't understand that last line.

Answer (score 0):

I made this regEx few days ago. 
If you use it like this it will give you an array of all palindromes in a certain text. 
The example is for #JavaScript but you can use the regEx itself in any language to do the job.
Works perfect for words to 21 chars or numbers to 21 digits. You can make it more accurate if you need to.

---

```
const palindromeFinder = /\b(\w?)(\w?)(\w?)(\w?)(\w?)(\w?)(\w?)(\w?)(\w?)(\w)\S?\10\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1\b/g;

console.log(inputString.match(palindromeFinder));
```

Comment: That's really inefficient to match anything which isn't a palindrome, as the regex engine will try all combination of matching/non-matching a char for each `\w?`. That's on top of its limited usefulness due to its 21 character restriction.