# "Quantifier quantifies nothing" but I never asked for a quantifier

Tags: regex, perl, raku, quantifiers

Consider the following Perl-flavoured?? (i suppose not?) [regex to test if a string is a palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349358/finding-palindrome-using-regex):

```
^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
```

[try it here](https://regex101.com/r/cL5sE8/1).

the following

```
my regex palindrome {
    ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
}

say "$word is a palindrome"
    if $word ~~ /<palindrome>/
    && $word.chars > 1;
```

gives an error

```
===SORRY!===
Quantifier quantifies nothing
at /home/cat/projects/perl6/code/misc/words.pl6:6
------>   ^((.)(?⏏1)\2|.?)$
Unrecognized backslash sequence (did you mean $1?)
at /home/cat/projects/perl6/code/misc/words.pl6:6
------>   ^((.)(?1)\2⏏|.?)$
```

I have a working knowledge of (Python) regexes, and I get what it means when it says "Quantifier quantifies nothing", but I don't get *why* it says this when I was asking for recursion, not a quantification.

I don't have enough knowledge of Perl to know why it doesn't like the backslash (the other error).

I *did* try messing around with the syntax and searching around, but as far as I and the internet are concerned, this regex works, and fiddling with it generates various other errors I don't get.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's currently [a discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315419/176646) about whether the `perl` tag can also be added to Perl 6 questions, but please *always* include the `perl6` tag. Otherwise you'll confuse all the Perl 5 developers who will wonder why your code looks so funny.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot ahh, okay.

Comment: You need to double the pipe: `^((.)(?1)\2||.?)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same error, no change.

Comment: `(?1)` isn't a valid construct in Perl 6. Perl 6 regex isn't even remotely PCRE.

Comment: `(?1)` is a [recursive subpattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f_PARNO_%29-%28%3f-_PARNO_%29-%28%3f%2b_PARNO_%29-%28%3fR%29-%28%3f0%29) in Perl 5 regex, not a named capturing group. I'm not sure how to translate that into a Perl 6 regex (or if it can be done with a regex), but here are the [Perl 6 regex docs](https://doc.perl6.org/language/regexes). Be aware that the vast majority of Perl questions on SO ask about Perl 5, and trying to run Perl 5 code with Perl 6 will probably not work most of the time.

Comment: According to [this page](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html), it's `<~~>` to match the whole regex recursively, or you can specify a numbered ( `<~~0>`) or named ( `<~~foo>`) subpattern.

Comment: Well, backreferences like `\1` are also [gone](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Backslash_reform). Well, try `^((.)<~~1>$2||.?)$`. Or `^<(<(.)><~~1>$2||.?)>$` (*You may also capture a subset of the match using the `<(...)>` construct*)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: capture group indices are 0-based, and `~~` assertions for capture groups are not implemented...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is this:

```
my regex palindrome { (.) <~~> $0 || .? }
say "aba" ~~ /^<palindrome>$/;
```

Comment: this considers every word a palindrome.

Comment: @cat: not for me; what's your Rakudo version?

Comment: `This is Rakudo version 2015.12-219-gd67cb03 built on MoarVM version 2015.12-29-g8079ca5 implementing Perl 6.c.` Full disclosure: I ran it on `/usr/share/dict/words` and piped its output to a file, then `diff`ed the files and there were no differences.

Comment: I'm still on 2015.12-113, so I'll update and see what happens; could it be the problem lies elsewhere in your code?

Comment: This definitely matches every string, and it's not just my code because the same goes for `perl6 -e` and the REPL.

Comment: `$ perl6 -e 'my regex palindrome { (.) <~~> $0 || .? }; say "ab" ~~ /^<palindrome>$/' # Nil`

Comment: Oh! I had missed the `^` and `$` in the application of the regex. My mistake, you're right.