# Regex - No "p" at second position

Tags: regex

I am learning Regex and after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions), I started doing some exercises and I got stuck on this [exercise](http://regex.alf.nu/5). Here are the two lists of words that should be matched and not matched

[image]

I started with

```
^(.).*\1$
```

and get bothered with `sporous` that get matched although it should not. So I found

```
^(.)(?!p).*\1$
```

that did the trick.

The best solution (uses one less character than my solution) given [here](https://gist.github.com/jpsim/8057500) is

```
^(.)[^p].*\1$
```

but I don't really understand this pattern. Actually I think I am confused about seeing the `^` anchor in a group `[]` and I am confused about seeing the `^` anchor somewhere else than at the beginning of the regex.

Can you help to understand what this regex is doing?

Comment: For what it's worth, all of the words on the left are palindromes. There are more elegant solutions than excluding `p` as the second letter.

Comment: I thought about that at first but then I sumbled upon [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233243/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-a-palindrome-using-regular-expressions) that says that there is no way to match palindromes in regex

Comment: "No easy way" in this context probably means you need to figure out the hard way.

Comment: Yes, that's true, you can't match arbitrary palindromes. In this case though, you could match the first two letters against the last two. It's not a full match but it's better than `[^p]`, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything in square brackets is a character class.  This context uses its own mini-syntax which simply lists the allowed characters `[abc]` or a range of allowed characters `[a-z]` or disallowed characters by adding a caret as the very first character in the character class `[^a-z]`.

Comment: Does it mean that `^` means "beginning of the line" when it is in the beginning of a regex and means `NOT` when it is in a group `[]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  But only when it is the first character in the character class (not "group"; that's something else).

Answer (score 1):

`[^p]` simply means that any character will match, which is not `p`.

I'll explain the regex step by step in the following sentences.

```
^        start of the string
(.)      matches any character as group 1
[^p]     matches any character that is not p
 .*      matches any character that repeats zero or more times
 \1      matches the exact matched character(s) from group 1
 $       end of the string
```

A good source for learning regex is [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lP4mU9/1).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution uses a negative look-ahead `(?!p)` that does not consume characters, and just checks if the next character is not `p`.

The other solution uses a negated character class `[^p]` that will consume a character other than `p`.

So, the final solution depends on what you need to match/capture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pattern explanation of `^(.)[^p].*\1$`

```
^     start of the string/line
(.)   group first character
[^p]  any character except p
.*    zero or more characters
\1    first matched group again
$     end of the string/line
```

The above regex matches any string that starts and ends with the same character and not contains p at second position.

For detail explanation visit at [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Read more about [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 1):

`^` means assert position at start of the line, however, in a character class `[ ]` it equates to match character other than ...

**Example:**

```
^test-[^p]-1234
```

**Result:**

```
test-q-1234 // match
test-p-1234 // no match
test-o-1234 // match
```

https://regex101.com/r/wN4zF9/1