# Is it possible to find sequences of words using regex?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to find sequences where the ending letter of one word is the same as the beginning letter of the next word, and the ending letter of that word is the same as the beginning letter of the next next word and so on?

For example:

`elementum magna sodales` should match `elementum magna`, while something like `Proin nunc curna, aliquet nec` should return `Proin nunc curna, aliquet`, but `an earring` should return nothing because `n` is not the same as `e`.

I've tried something like `\w*(\w)[\s:;'",.?!]*\1\w*` but that only matches two words, I kind of need them to daisy chain together.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. At least for any regex engine supporting backreferences.

Comment: Could you show your attempts?

Comment: Are you asking this as a challenge (for fun), if not, what is your actual use case? There might be better ways to resolve this.

Comment: @d4nyll yeah, for fun. maybe there is a better way, i don't know.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've tried `\w*(\w)[\s:;'",.?!]*\1\w*` but that only matches two words, and I kind of need to daisy chain it together.

Comment: You should put that in your question (edit it), the lack of attempts is probably the reason of the downvote.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
(?i)\b(?:[a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]+(?=\1))+[a-z]*
```

Details:

```
(?i) # makes the pattern case-insensitive
\b
(?:  # non-capturing group: one word and eventual following non-word characters
    [a-z]*([a-z]) # a word with the capture of the last character
    [^a-z]+ # non-word characters
    (?=\1) # lookahead that checks the next word first letter
)+ # repeat
[a-z]* # last next word
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAmhEv/3)

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is theoretically possible if your regex-engine supports [recursive references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrecurse.html).

This problems is similar with checking if a string is palindrome (question: [How to check that a string is a palindrome using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233243/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-a-palindrome-using-regular-expressions)).

Comment: You don't need to use recursion for this problem. (You can also find palindromes without recursion).