# Check if a string is a palindrome in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, palindrome

I need to check if given string is a palindrome using PostgreSQL. The first approach that came into my mind is to use a regex.
I found a good regex example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40792780/1828296).

The regex is: `\A(?:(.)(?=.*?(\1\2?)\z))*?.?\2\z`.

It works just fine in my browser. But when I tried to apply it in PostgreSQL 11.2 (on Windows 10), it does not work as expected.

What I've tried so far:

1. Escaping backslashes (did not work):

   ```
   select '23200000232' ~ '\\\\A(?:(.)(?=.*?(\\\\1\\\\2?)\\\\Z))*?.?\\\\2\\\\Z' as r;
   ```

   Expected true, returned false.
2. Using special escaping syntax `E'...'` (did not work):

   `select '23200000232' ~ E'\A(?:(.)(?=.*?(\1\2?)\Z))*?.?\2\Z' as r;`

   Expected true, returned false.
   Meanwhile `select '23200000232' ~ E'232(.)+232' as r;` returns true as expected;
3. Executing `set standard_conforming_strings=on;` right before my query didn't help.
4. Using small `\Z` and capital `\Z` (according to the [PostgreSQL regex documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)) to define end of a string didn't help.

Comment: Try `'^(?:(.)(?=.*?(\1\2?)$))*?.?\2$'` or `'^(?:(.)(?=.*?(\\1\\2?)$))*?.?\\2$'`. Escaping backslashes may not be required, that depends on the options you have enabled or not in your PostgreSQL environment

Comment: Why a regex? `column = reverse(column)` would achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks, this also could be an accepted answer (because goal will be reached). But if I (or somebody else) will need to use regexp in PostgreSQL for different tasks, it could be nice to find a working exampe using regexp in PostgreSQL with backslashes.