# How to filter duplicated reversed words from the middle in Spark DataFrame Filter?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter a data frame by words that are reversed in the middle,
I want these words for example:

abba
abcddcba

Is there any regex or anything that can help me with this?

**Update**

It is impossible it seems:
[How to check that a string is a palindrome using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233243/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-a-palindrome-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: What if you have an odd number of charaters? e.g. abcba

Comment: I think the middle char should be ignored, but currently I will apperisiate a regex that works with even characters only too

Comment: Why would you need regex?  simply size and find middle point and string unstring in a loop

Comment: Probably not possible with Regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233243/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-a-palindrome-using-regular-expressions