# Printing all palindromes from text file

Tags: bash, palindrome

I looked at this question: [BASH Palindrome Checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601234/bash-palindrome-checker). This is what the question answer shows from that thread:

```
grep -E '^[a-z]{3,45}$' /usr/share/dict/words | while read -r word;
    do [ $word == `echo $word | rev` ] && echo $word;
done;
```

I understand that this is reading from "words" but have trouble trying to modify it to read from a text file instead of `/usr/share/dict/words`. I want to have it to read any text file I request, so I can put:

```
source palindrome *filename*
```

and this will print out the palindromes found in the file in the console. Also later to have it so I can output to a output file:

```
source palindrome *filename* >> output.txt
```

I have tried to do this but it doesn't work and I am really not sure what I have to change to get it to read my file:

```
#!usr/bin/bash

function search
{
    filename=$1

    grep -E '^[a-z]{3,45}$' "$filename" | while read -r word;
        do [ $word == `echo $word | rev` ] && echo $word;
    done;
}
search $1
```

If any solutions are given could they be in a similar format? I haven't learned too many other techniques yet. If more complicated solutions are given could you explain the code given a little please.

---

The input file is from an eBook, it is extremely long so a small snippet is: (I do realise this doesn't show off palindromes in the snippet but it is just to show what kind of text file it is)

```
O and that lotion mustn't forget.
Fever near her mouth. Your head it simply. Hair braided over: shell with
seaweed. Why do they hide their ears with seaweed hair?
```

When running source palindrome *filename* there is no error message. I press enter and the terminal lets me type anything I want in again. It doesn't look as if it is running through the script

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not a problem description.

Comment: Have you error message ?

Comment: Why do you need to source the bash code if you are just dumping the result to a file? Wouldn't it be better to define as a regular bash/sh script?

Comment: Cristian Ramon-Cortes - I want to output it to the terminal to begin with so I can check if it works as intended, then I will output it to a file afterwards

Comment: @Jhonathan, this could be done with awk one-liner (with only clarification of minimum word size processed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

function search
{
    grep -oiE '[a-z]{3,}' "$@" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | while read -r word; do
        [[ $word == $(rev <<< "$word") ]] && echo "$word"
    done
}

search "$@"
```

The dictionary this original code was written for had a single lowercase word on each line. To parse a text file with multiple mixed case words per line you need a few modifications:

- Remove the `^` and `$` anchors from the regex to find words anywhere on a line.
- Use `grep -o` to print out the matching words.
- Use `grep -i` to match both upper and lowercase.
- Use `tr` to switch uppercase letters to lowercase.

Other fixes:

- Changed the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`. It ought to be an absolute path, and the two preferred forms are either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.
- Changed `£word` to `$word`.
- Use `"$@"` so `search()` can accept multiple file names.

Improvements:

- There's no particular reason to limit words to 45 characters. `{3,}` removes the upper limit.
- Double brackets `[[ ]]` are [better than single brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/3427931#3427931) `[ ]`.
- `$(cmd)` is better than `` `cmd` ``.
- `rev <<< "$word"` is better than `echo "$word" | rev`.

Comment: Just a couple of  questions:      1: with the "$@" so it can accept multiple files, in my code of $1 that would mean it takes one file?     2: With the "{3,}" part, does this mean it accepts words that are ONLY 3 or more long rather than my code than did between 3-45 characters long.

Comment: 1: That's right, `$1` means it only takes one file. 2: It now accepts words of unlimited length rather than limiting them to 45 characters. 3-infinity is better than 3-45.

Answer (score 1):

Your shebang line is wrong. Change:

```
#!usr/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: The `$*` part is nonsense.

Comment: Why `$*`is nonsense ? When he call `source palindrome *filename*`  $* can be expanded by `a_filename1` `another_filename_2` ...

Comment: So how would that work with `filename=$*; grep -E '^[a-z]{3,45}$' "$filename"`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this (no scripting):

```
comm -12 <(nl foo) <(rev foo | nl) | cut -f2
```