# Bash - Count frequency of palindromes from text file

Tags: bash, palindrome

This is a follow up from my other post:
[Printing all palindromes from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014928/printing-all-palindromes-from-text-file)

I want to be able to print to amount of palindromes that I have found from my text file similar to a frequency table. It'll show the amount of the word followed by the word, similar to this format:

```
100  did
32   sas
17   madam
```

My code right now is:

```
#!usr/bin/env bash

function search
{
    grep -oiE '[a-z]{3,}' "$1" | sort -n | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | while read -r word; do
        [[ $word == $(rev <<< "$word") ]] && echo "$word" | uniq -c
    done
}
search "$1"
```

In comparison to the last post I did: [Printing all palindromes from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014928/printing-all-palindromes-from-text-file) . I have added "sort -n" and "uniq -c" which from my knowledge is to sort the palindromes found in alphabetical order, then "uniq -c" is to print the number of occurrences of the words found.

Just to test script I have a testing file named: "testingfile.txt" . This contains:

```
testing words testing words testing words 
palindromes
Sas
Sas
Sas
sas
bob
Sas
Sas
Sas Sas madam
midim poop goog tot sas did i want to go to the movies did
otuikkiuto

pop
poop
```

This file is just so I can test before trying this script on a much larger file in which it'll take much longer.

When typing in the console: (also to note "palindrome" is the name of my script)

```
source palindrome testingfile.txt
```

The output appears like this:

```
1 bob
1 did
1 did
1 goog
1 madam
1 midim
1 otuikkiuto
1 poop
1 poop
1 pop
1 sas
1 sas
1 sas
1 sas
1 sas
1 sas
1 sas
1 sas
1 sas
1 tot
```

Is there something I am missing to get the result that I want:

```
9 sas
2 did
2 poop
1 bob
1 goog
1 madam
1 midim
1 otuikkiuto
1 pop
1 tot
```

Solutions to this would be greatly appreciated! If there are solutions with other commands that are needed an explanation of the reasoning behind the other commands are also greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed two important details:

- You need to pass *all input at once* to `uniq -c` to count them, not one by one to one `uniq` each
- `uniq` expects its input to be sorted. The `sort` you had in the `grep` pipeline is ineffective, because after the transformation to lowercase, the values would need to be sorted again

You can apply `sort | uniq -c` to the output of an entire loop,
by piping the loop itself:

```
grep -oiE '[a-z]{3,}' "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | while read -r word; do
    [[ $word == $(rev <<< "$word") ]] && echo "$word"
done | sort | uniq -c
```

Finally, to get an output sorted in descending order by count,
you need to further pipe the output to `sort -nr`.

Comment: So in my code was it looping through and doing "uniq -c" on each word found? And then in your code supplied it will do "uniq -c once it finishes reading through the entire file?

Comment: @Jhonathan yes you were running `uniq` once for each file. If you pipe the loop itself to `| sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`, then you will be filtering all the output produced in the loop's body.

Comment: also by any chance from the answer you gave my previous question, would this then mean the script will run faster as it'll be doing less work on each loop?

Comment: @Jhonathan yes it will run much faster, because it will run much fewer processes